# Docker isn't mounting the directory? "OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: no such file or directory: unknown"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-10-desktop, docker-toolbox

On my Windows 10 Home computer with Docker Toolbox, Docker is having trouble mounting the drives. I've already run dos2unix on the entrypoint.sh file.

The full error is as such:

```
ERROR: for users  Cannot start service users: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh\": stat /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  users:
    build:
      context: ./services/users
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    entrypoint: ['/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh']
    volumes:
      - './services/users:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_dev
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_test
    depends_on:
      - users-db
```

Curiously, when I comment out the "volumes" section, it works! But I want to be able to mount volumes in the future.

Directory structure can be seen as such:

```
D:\flask-react-auth
│   .gitignore
│   .gitlab-ci.yml
│   docker-compose.yml
│   README.md
│   release.sh
│   
└───services
    │   
    └───users
        │   .coveragerc
        │   .dockerignore
        │   Dockerfile
        │   Dockerfile.prod
        │   entrypoint.sh
        │   manage.py
        │   requirements-dev.txt
        │   requirements.txt
        │   setup.cfg
        │   tree.txt
        │   
        └───project
            │   config.py
            │   __init__.py
            │   
            ├───api
            │   │   ping.py
            │   │   __init__.py
            │   │   
            │   └───users
            │           admin.py
            │           crud.py
            │           models.py
            │           views.py
            │           __init__.py
            │           
            ├───db
            │       create.sql
            │       Dockerfile
            │       
            └───tests
                    conftest.py
                    pytest.ini
                    test_admin.py
                    test_config.py
                    test_ping.py
                    test_users.py
                    test_users_unit.py
                    __init__.py
```

I have added the `D:\flask-react-auth\` to the 'Shared Folders' on virtualbox as well.

Comment: Does the `entrypoint.sh` script have DOS or Unix line endings?  Does it name an interpreter that doesn't exist (Alpine-based images will have a `/bin/sh` but not GNU Bash, for example)?

Comment: I ran dos2unix on entrypoint.sh, so that should be taken care of. It is using alpine linux. The crazy thing is that it's able to  `RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh` from the dockerfile! This error happens for some mysterious reason **after** the dockerfile has finished running

Comment: It doesn't matter what you've done to files from the Dockerfile when you mount a volume over top of them. Dockerfile makes the image, and volume applies to the container (build vs run).

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems obvious to me:

When you run the code as is
* it mounts the current working directory to '/usr/src/app'.
* The current working directory does not have a file 'entrypoint.sh'.
* It tries to run '/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh' but it is not there so it fails.

When you comment out that volume mount
* I assume the image already has '/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh' so it just works.

I think you probably should change the mounting code from

```
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
```

to

```
    volumes:
      - './services/users:/usr/src/app'
```

Comment: What if you changed `entrypoint: ['/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh']` to `entrypoint: ['sh', '/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh']`.  If that does not work can you change it temporarily to `entrypoint: ['ls', '/usr/src/app']` `entrypoint: ['stat', '/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh']` to see what that output that gives you.